# Нету ответа от бота, что делать?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Бот начинает свою работу, в терминале пишет "BOT STARTED" без каких либо ошибок, но при отправке команды /start, ничего не происходит

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
import asyncio
import requests

PROBIVAPI_KEY = "YOUR_PROBIVAPI_KEY_HERE"

API_TOKEN = "6856201616:*****ZmTPylSaR0p1s4q0BkcKPkti_O4Tbw"

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()

print("!BOT STARTED!")

async def get_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Привет, введи айди человека")

async def send_help(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("soon")

async def text(message: types.Message):
    nomer = message.text
    print(nomer)

    url = "https://api.com/info/" + nomer

    head = {
        "X-Auth": PROBIVAPI_KEY
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=head)
    print(response.text)

    try:
        json_response = response.json()
    except Exception:
        json_response = {}

    try:
        truecaller_api_name = str(json_response['truecaller']['data'][0]['name'])
    except Exception:
        truecaller_api_name = 'Not found'
    try:
        numbuster_api_name = str(json_response['numbuster']['averageProfile']['firstName']) + \
                             str(json_response['numbuster']['averageProfile']['lastName'])
    except Exception:
        numbuster_api_name = 'Not found'
    try:
        eyecon_api_name = str(json_response['eyecon'])
    except Exception:
        eyecon_api_name = 'Not found'
    try:
        viewcaller_name_list = []
        for tag in json_response['viewcaller']:
            viewcaller_name_list.append(tag['name'])
        viewcaller_api_name = ', '.join(viewcaller_name_list)
    except Exception:
        viewcaller_api_name = 'Not found'

    await message.reply(
        f" База: (Numbuster): {numbuster_api_name}\n"
        f" База: (EyeCon): {eyecon_api_name}\n"
        f" База: (ViewCaller): {viewcaller_api_name}\n"
        f" База: (TrueCaller): {truecaller_api_name}"
    )

async def main():
    dp.register_message_handler(get_start, commands="/start")
    dp.register_message_handler(send_help, commands="/help")
    bot = Bot(API_TOKEN)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/index.html#simple-usage

Answer (score 0):

Убери / из `dp.register_message_handler(get_start, commands="/start")`
Должно остаться:

```py
async def main():
    dp.register_message_handler(get_start, commands="start")
    dp.register_message_handler(send_help, commands="help")
    bot = Bot(API_TOKEN)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
```